# Spectrum of a product of rings isomorphic to the product of the spectra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I've found in an exercise this statement:

If $A$ is a commutative ring with unit and $A = A_{1} \times \dots \times A_{n}$ then $$\def\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}} \Spec(A) \cong  \Spec(A_{1})\times \dotsb \times \Spec(A_{n})$$ Why is this true ?

Comment: I suppose they are direct product of prime ideals, but why ?

Comment: @WLOG Note that a product of rings is never an integral domain, so the product of prime ideals can't be prime in general.

Comment: I hope my edit is useful. I took the liberty of rewriting the title of the question to make it more easy to find when searching the site.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is not true. Direct products of rings correspond to *disjoint unions* of affine schemes. *Tensor products*, on the other hand, correspond to fibre products (in particular, products) of affine schemes.

Explicitly,

$$\operatorname{Spec}(A_1\times\cdots\times A_n) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(A_1)\sqcup\cdots\sqcup \operatorname{Spec}(A_n)$$ and

$$\operatorname{Spec}(A_1\otimes_R A_2) \cong \operatorname{Spec}(A_1)\times_{\operatorname{Spec} R}\operatorname{Spec}(A_2).$$

The reason for this is that the functor $\operatorname{Spec}$ is a contravariant equivalence from the category $\operatorname{Ring}$ of commutative unital rings to the category $\operatorname{Aff}$ of affine schemes. In particular, it sends (fibre) products to (fibre) coproducts, and vice versa. The product in $\operatorname{Ring}$ is the cartesian product $\times$ and the coproduct in $\operatorname{Aff}$ is disjoint union $\sqcup$, giving the first statement above. The fibre coproduct in $\operatorname{Ring}$ is given by the tensor product, giving the second statement above.

Without resorting to abstract nonsense, we can see the bijection between $\operatorname{Spec}(A_1\times A_2)$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(A_1)\sqcup\operatorname{Spec}(A_2)$ as follows: the prime ideals of $A_1\times A_2$ are of the form $\mathfrak{p}\times A_2$ where $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal of $A_1$, or $A_1\times\mathfrak q$ where $\mathfrak q$ is a prime ideal of $A_2$.

Comment: Where can I find the proof ?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include some explanation.

Comment: The assertion "direct products of rings correspond to disjoint unions of affine schemes" is only true in the finite case (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

This isn't true. Consider the simple case where $A_1 = A_2 = \mathbb{C}[x]$. Then $Spec(A_i) = \mathbb{C}$.

However, $Spec(A_1 \times A_2) = \mathbb{C} \sqcup \mathbb{C}$, not $\mathbb{C}^2 = Spec(A_1 \otimes A_2)$.

Comment: The max spec of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is $\mathbb{C}$ but the prime spec has an extra point.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\Spec{\operatorname{Spec}}$The direct product of the rings $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ equals the disjoint union of the spectra if and only if $I$ is finite (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/269966/394668)). That is, the inclusion $\text{Aff}\to\text{LRS}$ does not preserve coproducts in general (where $\text{LRS}$ is the category of locally ringed spaces). What's true for formal reasons is that $\Spec(A_1\otimes_R A_2)=\Spec A_1\times_{\Spec R}\Spec A_2$, for the functor $\Spec:\text{Ring}^\mathrm{op}\to\text{LRS}$ is a right adjoint, so it preserves all limits. But we need a non-formal argument to show that that $\Spec(A_1\times A_2)$ is the coproduct of $\Spec A_1$ and $\Spec A_2$ in the category of locally ringed spaces (i.e., it equals the disjoint union of the spectra). Such an argument is to be found for instance in [00ED](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00ED) and [01I5](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01I5).

This result has the following intuitive meaning: if $M$ is a smooth (resp., complex) manifold and $\mathcal{O}_M$ is the structure sheaf of smooth real-valued (resp., holomorphic complex-valued) functions, then $\Gamma(M,\mathcal{O}_M)=\prod_{C\subset M}\mathcal{O}_M(C)$, where $C$ moves across the connected components of $M$ (which is a locally connected topological space, so its connected components are open). If the spectrum of a ring $A$ is to be thought of as the geometric space whose functions are the elements of $A$, then the isomorphism of affine schemes
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}
\Spec(A_1\times A_2)\cong\Spec(A_1)\amalg\Spec(A_2)
$$
can be understood in analogy with the smooth/complex manifold situation. (Note that this fails for the infinite ring product, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/269966/394668).) Actually, in the classical setting it's more than analogy: a finite disjoint union of classical affine k-varieties is again a classical affine k-variety ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1026953/394668)'s the question addressing this issue). In the case $\overline{k}=k$, this follows from the classical-schematic equivalence (see [here](https://eliasguisado.wordpress.com/work/) or [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emhaiman/math256-fall18-spring19/varieties-as-schemes-v2.pdf)) plus the isomorphism \eqref{1} and the fact that finitely-generated reduced k-algebras are stable under finite direct products.

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma.** $\operatorname{Spec}(A\times B)=\operatorname{Spec}(A)\sqcup\operatorname{Spec}(B)$.

*Proof.*
Take an element $\mathfrak p$ of $\operatorname{Spec}(A\times B)$ and define
$$
            \mathfrak p_A=\pi_A(\mathfrak p)\quad\text{and}\quad\mathfrak p_B=\pi_B(\mathfrak p),
$$
where $\pi_A$ and $\pi_B$ are the projections. Note that $\mathfrak p_A$ is an ideal that satisfies $aa'\in\mathfrak p_A\implies a\in\mathfrak p_A$ or $a'\in\mathfrak p_A$. Thus, if $\mathfrak p_A$ is proper, it is prime in $A$. Similarly for $\mathfrak p_B$. It follows that $\mathfrak p_A\times B$ (resp. $A\times\mathfrak p_B$) is prime when $\mathfrak p_A$ (resp. $\mathfrak p_B$) is proper.

**Claim:** *One, and only one, of $\mathfrak p_A$ and $\mathfrak p_B$ is proper.*

Indeed. Suppose that $1\notin\mathfrak p_A$. Pick $b\in\mathfrak p_B$. There exists $a\in A$ such that $(a,b)\in\mathfrak p$. Therefore, $(a,1)(1,b)=(a,b)\in\mathfrak p$. But $(1,b)\notin\mathfrak p$, or we would have $1\in\mathfrak p_A$, which is not. Hence, $(a,1)\in\mathfrak p$, implying that $1\in\mathfrak p_B$. In other words, not both of them are proper. Moreover, in case $\mathfrak p_A$ is proper, we also have $\mathfrak p_A\times B\subseteq\mathfrak p$. Conversely, if $(a,b)\in\mathfrak p$, then $a\in\mathfrak p_A$ and so $(a,b)\in\mathfrak p_A\times B$, i.e., equality is attained. Finally, suppose that $\mathfrak p_A=A$ and $\mathfrak p_B=B$. Then $(1,b)\in\mathfrak p$ for some $b\in B$ and $(a,1)\in\mathfrak p$ for some $a\in A$. It follows that $(1,1) = (1,0)(1,b) + (0,1)(a,1) \in\mathfrak p$,
which is impossible. The claim is now clear.

We conclude that
$$
  \operatorname{Spec}(A\times B) \subseteq
               \operatorname{Spec}(A)\sqcup\operatorname{Spec}(B).
$$
Since the other inclusion is obvious, equality is attained.