# Spectrum of infinite product of rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, schemes, products, maximal-and-prime-ideals, affine-schemes

$\def\Z{{\mathbb{Z}}\,}
\def\Spec{{\rm Spec}\,}$
Suppose $R$ a ring and consider $\Spec(\prod_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} R)$. Now for the finite case, I know that holds $\Spec(R \times R) = \Spec(R) \coprod \Spec(R)$.

My intutition says that this does not extend to the infinite case. Maybe $\Spec(\oplus_{i \in \Z} R) = \coprod_{i \in \Z}\Spec(R)$ holds, but I am not sure. Can anybody give a proof or counter example for both the infinite direct sum and direct product?

Comment: Note that the spectrum of any ring is quasi-compact. However, $\coprod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} X$ is never quasi-compact if $X$ is not empty. So $\coprod_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} X$ is never the spectrum of a ring.

Comment: And $\bigoplus_{i \in I} R$ is not a ring if $I$ is infinite. In general, it's bad practice to write direct sum for rings (even if $I$ is finite), because it only satisfies the universal property for the direct product (and not that of the coproduct).

Comment: Ah yeah you are right, I forgot it had no 1! Thnx :)

Answer (score 7):

The spectrum of an infinite direct product is complicated. For example, the spectrum of an infinite direct product $\prod_{i \in I} F_i$ of fields can canonically be identified with the space $\beta I$ of [ultrafilters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) on $I$, also known as the [Stone-Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification) of $I$. For more on this in the special case that each $F_i$ is $\mathbb{F}_2$ see [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/boolean-rings-ultrafilters-and-stones-representation-theorem/).

In general the spectrum of an arbitrary infinite direct product $\prod_{i \in I} R_i$ fibers over $\beta I$, where the fiber over an ultrafilter $U \in \beta I$ is the spectrum of the [ultraproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) $\prod_{i \in I} R_i / U$. For more on this see Eric Wofsey's excellent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1534543/232) and [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/28/connected-components-in-a-distributive-category/).