# Ring of "Sequences up to finitely many entries"

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Given any ring $R$ we can look at the ring of $R$-sequences $\text{Sets}(\mathbb N,R) \cong R^\mathbb N$. Take the quotient $R^\mathbb N/\sim$ by the equivalence relation ~ given by setting two sequences equivalent if they agree up to finitely many terms. Does this ring have a specific name in the literature?

Also:
The diagonal map $R \xrightarrow{\Delta} R^\mathbb N$ induces an $R$-algebra structure on $R^\mathbb N/\sim$. Is $\text{Spec}(R^\mathbb N/\sim)$ in any way interesting as a scheme over $R$?

Comment: You just constructed a quotient ring $R^{\mathbb N}/R^{(\mathbb N)}$, where $R^{(\mathbb N)}$ is the direct sum of countable many copies of $R$, or if you like it, the ideal of sequences having only finitely many non-zero entries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a name for this ring, but let me say a little about its spectrum.  Let $S=R^\mathbb{N}/\sim$.  For any subset $A\subset\mathbb{N}$, there is an element $e_A\in S$ which is $1$ on each element of $A$ and $0$ on each element of $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$.  These elements $e_A$ are idempotent, and $e_A=e_B$ iff the symmetric difference $A\mathbin{\Delta}B$ is a finite set.  If $P\subset S$ is a prime ideal, then $f(P)=\{A\in\mathbb{N}:1-e_A\in P\}$ is an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$.  Since $e_F=0$ for $F$ finite, $f(P)$ cannot contain any finite sets, so $f(P)$ is a nonprincipal ultrafilters.  This defines a continuous map $f:\operatorname{Spec} S\to \beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$, where $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ is the space of all nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$ (also known as the Stone-Cech remainder of $\mathbb{N}$).

We can get a handle on the fibers of this map $f$.  If $U$ is a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is just the closed subscheme of $\operatorname{Spec} S$ consisting of those prime ideals that contain $1-e_A$ for each $A\in U$.  That is, it is the spectrum of the quotient of $S$ by the ideal generated by these elements $1-e_A$ for $A\in U$.  Equivalently, it is the quotient of $R^{\mathbb{N}}$ by ideal generated by the elements $1-e_A$ in $R^{\mathbb{N}}$, since every cofinite set $A$ is in $U$ and the elements $1-e_A$ for $A$ cofinite exactly generate the kernel of the map $R^{\mathbb{N}}\to S$.  This quotient of $R^{\mathbb{N}}$ is better-known as the [ultrapower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) of $R$ by the ultrafilter $U$.

So to sum up, $\operatorname{Spec} S$ has a canonical continuous map to the space of nonprincipal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$, and the fibers of this map are the spectra of the ultrapowers of $R$.  If you were looking at $\operatorname{Spec} R^\mathbb{N}$ instead, the description would be exactly the same, except that you would also include the principal ultrafilters.  For more related discussion, you may be interested in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533237/spectrum-of-mathbbz-mathbbn) which focuses on the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$.