# Residue fields of $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, set-theory, ideals

Let $A:=\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ be the direct product of infinitely many copies of $\mathbb R$. Let $I_0$ be the ideal of all sequences of $A$ which have only finitely many nonzero entries. Then $I_0$ is a proper ideal of $A$. If $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, containing $I_0$, then can we say anything about the residue field $A/\mathfrak m$? Note that, the residue field cannot be equal to $\mathbb R$. To see this, consider the unit $(2,4,8,16,\ldots)$. If the residue field is $\mathbb R$ then there exists a real number $c$ such that the $(c,c,c,\ldots)-(2,4,8,\ldots)$ is contained in $\mathfrak m$. But at most one entry of the difference is equal to zero. If the $i$'th entry of the difference is zero, then we can add to it the sequence which has $1$ at the $i$-th entry and zero everywhere else to conclude that $\mathfrak m$ contains a unit!

Comment: My own off-hand reaction is that that field might have large transcendence degree, to begin with...

Comment: This argument only shows that the composition of the quotient map to the residue field with the diagonal inclusion of R into the infinite product cannot be surjective. If you replace R with C, then all the residue fields will be isomorphic to C by Los’s ultraproduct theorem + cardinality. I wouldn’t be surprised if something similar holds here. 

At the very least, every residue field has continuum cardinality, lacks a square root of -1, and becomes algebraically closed of characteristic 0 as soon as such a root is adjoined.

Comment: Strictly speaking, what you said is correct. But here we are only considering $\mathbb R$-algebra isomorphisms. Besides, since $\mathbb R$ is not isomorphic to any proper subfield of it, the argument actually shows that the residue field $A/\mathfrak m$, even as an abstract field, is not isomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Duplicates of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1992025) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1533237) (with many more links within these two)

Comment: @Rafi The ultrapower (residue field) is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ because it is non-Archimedean: the residue class of $(1,2,3,4,\dots)$ is greater than $1$ added to itself $n$ times, for all finite $n$. To the OP: I don't understand why in the previous comment you said "$\mathbb{R}$ is not isomorphic to any proper subfield of it". The elements of the form $(r,r,r,r,\dots)$ form a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I think they meant that $\mathbb{R}$ is not isomorphic to any proper subfield of *itself*.

Comment: Thank you Eric for the clarification. Yes, i meant that $\mathbb R$ is not isomorphic to any proper subfield of itself.

Comment: Oh, I see! But is it clear that the ultrapower is isomorphic to a proper subfield of itself?

Comment: I don't know. I am not familiar with the ultrapower construction, just heard its name a few times. I only know that $\mathbb R$ is not isomorphic to any proper subfield of itself and $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to uncountably many proper subfields of itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the [ultrapower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) construction. There is a bijection between maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$ extending $I_0$ and non-principal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$, as explained by Eric Wofsey [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1992053/7062).

The resulting residue field is a [real closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field) of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ which is [$\aleph_1$-saturated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_model), also known as a [hyperreal field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number).

Comment: Thank you Alex for the to the point answer and useful references. I'll have a look at them.