# Maximal and prime ideal of $R:=\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $m$ be an integer such that $m \ge 2$. We define $R$ as the countable direct product
of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$
$$R:=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$$
I am trying to prove that the dimension of $R$ is $0$.
Which means I have to prove that all the prime ideal of $R$ is also a maximum ideal of $R$ ($*$).
It is obviously that if $m$ is prime then it only have $1$ element in $\operatorname{Spec} R$, then it's maximal.
But I don't know how to show ($*$) when m is not a prime number.

The ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ have the form $(d)$, where $d$ divides $m$. And the maxium ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is look like $(p)$ where $p$ is a  prime dividing $m$.

Let$$R_i=\prod_{n=1}^i \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$$

The ideal of $R_2$, looks like $(d_1)\times (d_2)$, $(d_1)\times R_1$ or $R_1\times (d_2)$ , but the ideal of $R_2$ is a prime ideal iff $(p)\times R_1$ or $R_1 \times (p)$ and $p$ is prime (1) and is also a maximal ideal(2) (if (1)(2) are true I think I can prove it). But I am not sure if (1) and (2) are true. And what I could do when $i$ is $\infty$?

Comment: I think you make a mistake on (1) the pirme ideal shoud be$<p>\times \mathbb{z}/m\mathbb{z}$ or $\mathbb{z}/m\mathbb{z}\times <p>$

Comment: @kingzone yes I have make this mistake, I have edited it thank you.

Comment: @KentaS thank you for your comment, I was wondinring if this work when n is $\infty$?

Comment: It doesnt. The disjoint union is not quasi compact while it should be if it would be the spectrum of a ring.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529988/spectrum-of-infinite-product-of-rings

This might be of interest?

Comment: @PaulK Thank you for your comment, I will go and reed this questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was posted as an answer to essentially the same question about by [Angina Seng](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/angina-seng) a few weeks ago, but the [question was deleted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749580/the-dimension-of-prod-limits%e2%88%9e-m-1-mathbbz-n-mathbbz) for other reasons. I thought the answer was instructive, so I'm reproducing it here, as a community-wiki post:

> You need to show that all prime ideals are maximal. Let $R$ denote the ring in question,
> then the prime ideals of $R$ are the kernels of ring homomorphisms $\phi:R\to K$
> where $K$ is a field. As $R$ has characteristic $n$, the characteristic
> of $K$ must be a prime $p$ dividing $n$. This means that the kernel
> of $\phi$ contains $\prod(p\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z)$ and so $R$ factors through $R'=
> \prod(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$. In effect we can suppose that $n=p$ with $p$ prime.
>
> Each element of $R'$ satisfies $x^p=x$. The same is true for the image of $\phi$.
> So the image of $\phi$ must be contained in the prime subfield $K_0$ of $K$
> with $p$ elements. Therefore $\phi(R)=K_0$ which is a field. Therefore
> $\ker \phi$ is a maximal ideal of $R$.

Comment: Thank your for your reproducing. May I ask why $\phi(R)$ must be contained in the prime subfield $K_0$?

Comment: The prime subfield of a field of characteristic $p$ is the unique subfield where all elements satisfy $x^p=x$. All elements in $\phi(R)$ satisfy this equation, so they must belong to that subfield.