# infinite family of rings product

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let R = $$\prod_{i\in \Delta }Z_{i} $$
where $$Z_{i} $$ Rings of integer
It's obvious that the product of a rings is itself a ring
And in finite case the ideal of the product = Product of Ideals
that is if I is an ideal of R , then  $$I = \prod_{i\in \Delta }I_{i}$$  and $$\Delta $$ is finite
now the question is what if $$ \Delta  $$ is infinite
can we still have $$I = \prod_{i\in \Delta }I_{i}$$ ?

Comment: No, in general there are many more ideals.

Comment: See, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1563190/232